# How to disable MS chart series grouping in C#?

Tags: c#, charts, series

My chart series are really near by each other and this is a problem. I don't know why they are grouped, they look like : http://i39.tinypic.com/wks007.png or http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/alexgor/WindowsLiveWriter/DataBindingMSChartcontrol_10712/image_2.png, but must be separate :(

I want to have each bar with his own name without grouping.
Like on second image, Andrew has 5 Columns near by each other with one title: "Andrew", but I want to have them separately)

How I can do this?

I use the MS chart library

P.S. excuse me for my english :)

My code example:

```
var table = new DataTable();
s = chart1.Series.Add("Ser1");
s.XValueMember = "Col1";
s.YValueMembers = "Col1_Count";

s = chart1.Series.Add("Ser2");
s.XValueMember = "Col2";
s.YValueMembers = "Col2_Count";

s = chart1.Series.Add("Ser3");
s.XValueMember = "Col3";
s.YValueMembers = "Col3_Count";

table.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Col1_Count", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Col2_Count", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Col3", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Col3_Count", typeof(int));
```

Then i execute SqlCommand SELECT and add rows to table and then 
    chart1.DataBind();

Comment: Could you please post the code you use to fill the chart ?

Answer (score 0):

firstly, be sure you put the Charttype as Column in chart control like ChartType="Column", 
then, the XValueMember should be the same column, and Bindpoints to series with seperate dataview, like

```
 DataView sDt1 = table .DefaultView.ToTable(true, new[] { "Column_Identifier", "RecordCount" }).DefaultView;
 Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(sDt1, "Column_Identifier", sDt1, "RecordCount");
```

Comment: Data like: Name Product       Count
Andrew Product A 35
Andrew Product B 36
Andrew Product C 37
Andrew Product D 38
Andrew Other 39
David Product A 35
David Product B 36
David Product C 37
David Product D 38
David Other         39
Bryan Product A 35
Bryan Product B 36
Bryan Product C 37
Bryan Product D 38
Bryan Other         39